# Create a time series from data

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe which contains information on defaults within a loan portfolio and the time from origination from which it occurred.   Each 'observation' is a pair representing time t in days, and amount of loan default:

```
df['time_to_default']  #  Time from origination to default
df['default_amnt']     #  The loan amount defaulted
```

I would like to create a series which represents the cumulative amount of defaults for any given time t.  (Assume that time_to_default is evenly divisible by t).  I cannot figure out how to create a new dataframe element, assign the initial value to 0 and then iterate through the series....

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to simply add a index column? like `df['new_col'] = np.arange(len(df))`?

Comment: @EdChum - not exactly.   'new_col' will be populated as a function of the prior row's contents, e.g., df ['new_col'] = f( df['time_to_default'][t-1], df['default_amt][t-1]), where t is the index of the series.   I'm not certain the most pythonic way to reference this.  PS - This is a dataframe, can I use np?

Comment: Yes you can use numpy functions

Comment: Yes, that created a series.  But see my question - what's the best way to design a method to fill the series by recursive reference to other features in the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use `groupby` for this together with `cumsum` since you want a running total:

```
cum_defaults = df.groupby('time_to_default').default_amnt.sum().cumsum()
```

You then need to reindex this new series to fill in any missing days:

```
cum_defaults = cum_defaults.reindex(index=range(min(cum_defaults.index),
                                                max(cum_defaults.index) + 1), 
                                    method='ffill')
```

With some example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_to_default': [1, 3, 3, 6], 
                   'default_amnt': [10, 20, 30, 40]})
>>> cum_defaults
time_to_default
1     10
2     10
3     60
4     60
5     60
6    100
Name: default_amnt, dtype: int64
```